# Typescript DateTime comparison - Operator '=' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'DateTime'

Tags: typescript, datetime

I have a function where I would like to check if the time in format - 'HH:mm' is in between 2 set times:

```
export const getEarliestPickupTIme = (pickupTimeFrom?: ISOTimeString, pickupTimeTo?: ISOTimeString): ISOTimeString => {
  const timeNow = DateTime.local()

  if (pickupTimeTo && pickupTimeFrom) {
    const from = toLocaleDate(pickupTimeFrom)
    const to = toLocaleDate(pickupTimeTo)

    const isBetween = from >= timeNow <= to

    return isBetween ? timeNow.toFormat('HH:mm') : pickupTimeFrom
  }
  return timeNow.toFormat('HH:mm')
}
```

But, I get a typescript error if I do it like that:

```
Operator '=' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'DateTime'.
```

How can I compare times without getting this error?

Comment: Side-note `from >= timeNow <= to` is `(from >= timeNow) <= to` which is `<boolean> <= to`. Which is `true` for  `to >= 1`

Comment: ^^ e.g., you need `const isBetween = from >= timeNow && timeNow <= to;`. (There's probably a better dupetarget, if anyone knows of one please add it and ping me.)

Comment: Although, I don't see how the code would produce the error reported here. Unless the error is "Operator ***'<='*** cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'DateTime'." with the relational operator `<=` rather than assignment `=`